# How to Include space on number input?

Tags: html, forms

How to include the spaces (not text, 
only spaces and numbers) on the input type? 
 When i try my code it only includes numbers

**This is my code:**

```
<form action="/action_page.php"><input type="number"/><input type="submit"</form>
```

Comment: You cannot achieve this with the type"number" as the specification allows it to store one number only. Although a workaround is possible with JS, its not advisable as you are no longer sticking to the specifications of the type.

Comment: please give a descriptive explanation of what you want and all you have tried! and about the question what you want to achieve that you only accept number and space in input??

Comment: If it not possible in html then please tell me how to do it on javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9 ]+" />
    <input type="submit"</form>
```

you can use input with type text and add pattern `"[0-9 ]+"`.

Comment: It not working. the text is also included. what i mean is only space and numbers.

Comment: function isNumberKey(evt) {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode ;
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57 || charCode == 30 ))
                return false;

            return true;
        } .   you can call this method on onChange of input.

Comment: It will not allow you to add anything except numbers and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `type="text"` for your input in order to format your value as you want. `type="number"` does not work with this kind of format.

```
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('fr-FR');

<input
  type="text"
  value={formatter.format(value)}
/>
```

Comment: English please.

Answer (score 0):

This option is perfect for me.

```html
<input type = "text" inputmode = "numeric">
```

```js
input.addEventListener("input", inputEvent => {
    input.value = input.value.replaceAll(/\D/g, "");
    
    if (inputEvent.inputType === "insertText"){
        input.value = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may be a valid approach, I think it's important to clarify that this is not using the input type "number" as the OP asked. The simple answer is that type number does not allow spaces.